# Get a particular URL in Node JS other ways

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, reddit

I have a REST API of Reddit. I am trying to parse the JSON output to get the URL of the responses. When I try to send the request, I get multiple outputs, but I am not sure how to do it as it's a random response.

```js
https
  .get("https://www.reddit.com/r/cute/random.json", resp => {
    let data = "";

    resp.on("data", chunk => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    resp.on("end", () => {
      console.log(obj.url);
    });
  })
  .on("error", err => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
```

This is the code I have got. I used the default Node's `http` library and I don't think it worked. I have never used any Node Libraries, so it will be helpful if you can suggest them too. And also let me know if what I have done is right.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use `https` library and not something like `node-fetch`? I have a `node-fetch` example, I can share with you.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I am completely new to Node JS, so I am not sure what to use. I just followed some blog post to get it.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yea, I am happy with using `node-fetch`. As long as I get the URL from the JSON response, that's all it matters.

Comment: you could try `axios` library. it's well documented and has wide support

Comment: @ChrisIhure Can [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) be used on backend?

Comment: @LBGUser I have added an answer, feel free to ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: @ChrisIhure I checked it, but isn't it just for front end as Praveen says? I had the same question.

Comment: @LBGUser it can be used both in client and server. Most people use it on the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `http` is a core library of Node JS, but I strongly suggest you to use something like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). Make sure you run the following command on your terminal (or cmd) where your `package.json` file exists:

```sh
$ npm install node-fetch
```

This will install the `node-fetch` library, which acts similarly to how the Web based `fetch` works.

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const main = async () => {
  const json = await fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/cute/random.json").then(
    res => res.json()
  );
  console.log(
    json
      .map(entry => entry.data.children.map(child => child.data.url))
      .flat()
      .filter(Boolean)
  );
};
main();
```

The URLs that you are looking for, I could find in the `data.children[0].data.url` so I did a map there. I hope this is something that might help you.

I get multiple output for the same code, run multiple times, because the URL you have used is a Random Article Fetching URL. From their [wiki](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/random):

> [/r/random](https://www.reddit.com/r/random) takes you to a random subreddit. You can find a link to [/r/random](https://www.reddit.com/r/random) in the header above. Reddit gold members have access to [/r/myrandom](https://www.reddit.com/r/myrandom), which is right next to the random button. Myrandom takes you to any of your subscribed subreddits randomly. [/r/randnsfw](https://www.reddit.com/r/randnsfw) takes you to a random NSFW (over 18) subreddit.

The output for me is like this:

```
[ 'https://i.redd.it/pjom447yp8271.jpg' ]   // First run
[ 'https://i.redd.it/h9b00p6y4g271.jpg' ]   // Second run
[ 'https://v.redd.it/lcejh8z6zp271' ]       // Third run
```

Since it has only one URL, I changed the code to get the first one:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const main = async () => {
  const json = await fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/cute/random.json").then(
    res => res.json()
  );
  console.log(
    json
      .map(entry => entry.data.children.map(child => child.data.url))
      .flat()
      .filter(Boolean)[0]
  );
};
main();
```

Now it gives me:

```
'https://i.redd.it/pjom447yp8271.jpg'   // First run
'https://i.redd.it/h9b00p6y4g271.jpg'   // Second run
'https://v.redd.it/lcejh8z6zp271'       // Third run
'https://i.redd.it/b46rf6zben171.jpg'   // Fourth run
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

I hope this helps you. Feel free to ask me if you need more help. Other alternatives include [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), but I am not sure if this can be used on backend.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very detailed. Let me check and tell you if it works.

Comment: @LBGUser Does it work? Lemme know, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this works, this is indeed perfect.